# Python tkinter keeping the order of the names consistent when shifting items across two list box

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I have two listbox that is able to shift items back and forth between them with the use of buttons. Right now, when shifting the items, it would take the index of the selected item and delete it. This item will then be rewritten in the other box but be inserted at the bottom which is not what I really want. Is there any way for me to keep the order of the names consistent using the dictionary index when shifting it to the other box? For example, shifting the 3rd item 'Joanne' before the 1st item 'Bill' from the right to the left box will still let the 1st item be displayed on top of the 3rd item.

I have tried using a dictionary which can be seen in my code but I was not able to figure out how to make it work with tkinter's curselection (one of tkinter's listbox method)

```
from tkinter import *

#Buttons to shift items in the listbox
def shift_right():
    index = left_box.curselection()

    for x in index [::-1]:
        d = left_box.get(x)
        right_box.insert(END,d) 
        left_box.delete(x)

def shift_right_all():
    left_box.delete(0, END)
    right_box.delete(0, END)
    for x in dictvar:
        right_box.insert(END, dictvar[x])

def shift_left():
    index = right_box.curselection()

    for x in index [::-1]:
        d = right_box.get(x)
        left_box.insert(END,d)
        right_box.delete(x)

def shift_left_all():
    left_box.delete(0, END)
    right_box.delete(0, END)
    for x in dictvar:
        left_box.insert(END, dictvar[x])

root = Tk()
root.geometry('330x200')

names = ['Bill', 'Jack', 'Joanne', 'Ann', 'Dave', 'Jane']
dictvar = { i : names[i] for i in range(0, len(names))}

left_box = Listbox(root, activestyle = 'none', highlightthickness = 0)
left_box.place(x=5, y=5)

right_button = Button(root, text='  >  ', command = shift_right)
right_button.place(x=148, y=5)

right_all_button = Button(root, text='>>', command = shift_right_all)
right_all_button.place(x=148, y=55)

left_button = Button(root, text='  <  ', command = shift_left)
left_button.place(x=148, y=105)

left_all_button = Button(root, text='<<', command = shift_left_all)
left_all_button.place(x=148, y=155)

right_box = Listbox(root, activestyle = 'none', highlightthickness = 0)
for x in dictvar:
    right_box.insert(END, dictvar[x])
right_box.place(x=200, y=5)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: The `insert` method lets you insert an item anywhere in the listbox. Does that solve your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you don't need the `dictvar`, just use `names` is enough.  In order to keep the order the same as `names` when inserting into listbox, you need to find the insertion position of the target listbox.

Below is a modified code based on yours:

```
from tkinter import *

# insert name into listbox
def insert_into(listbox, name):
    # get the index of name in names
    idx = names.index(name)
    # loop through listbox to find the insert position
    insert_idx = END
    for i in range(listbox.size()):
        if names.index(listbox.get(i)) > idx:
            insert_idx = i
            break
    listbox.insert(insert_idx, name)

#Buttons to shift items in the listbox
def shift_right():
    index = left_box.curselection()

    for x in index [::-1]:
        d = left_box.get(x)
        insert_into(right_box, d) 
        left_box.delete(x)

def shift_right_all():
    left_box.delete(0, END)
    right_box.delete(0, END)
    right_box.insert(END, *names)

def shift_left():
    index = right_box.curselection()

    for x in index [::-1]:
        d = right_box.get(x)
        insert_into(left_box, d)
        right_box.delete(x)

def shift_left_all():
    left_box.delete(0, END)
    right_box.delete(0, END)
    left_box.insert(END, *names)

root = Tk()
root.geometry('330x200')

names = ['Bill', 'Jack', 'Joanne', 'Ann', 'Dave', 'Jane']

left_box = Listbox(root, activestyle = 'none', highlightthickness = 0)
left_box.place(x=5, y=5)

right_button = Button(root, text='  >  ', command = shift_right)
right_button.place(x=148, y=5)

right_all_button = Button(root, text='>>', command = shift_right_all)
right_all_button.place(x=148, y=55)

left_button = Button(root, text='  <  ', command = shift_left)
left_button.place(x=148, y=105)

left_all_button = Button(root, text='<<', command = shift_left_all)
left_all_button.place(x=148, y=155)

right_box = Listbox(root, activestyle = 'none', highlightthickness = 0)
right_box.insert(END, *names)
right_box.place(x=200, y=5)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked like a charm. However, I'm new to python and coding itself so I'm not really able to figure out how the 'insert_into' function works, mind explaining it in details? Thank you in advance!

Comment: The for loop is to find the name in the target list with index in `names` greater than that of to be inserted name.  If found, just insert the name before the found name, otherwise insert at the end of the listbox/

Comment: Thank you very much for the help and prompt replies :D